# Empty soap postman response using spring boot

Tags: java, spring, soap, postman

I have set up a basic soap spring boot web service using the spring initializer.

I have set up a user endpoint and user service as well as a `soap web service config`. when sending the soap request in postman I get an empty response back

Comment: i was following the code found here as an example: https://github.com/TechPrimers/spring-boot-soap-example even when importing the repo i had the same issue

Comment: I recommend you use SOAP UI for sending SOAP messages.

Answer (score 0):

The sample you have posted seems to be inspired from the spring [Spring Sample](https://spring.io/guides/gs/producing-web-service/) 
There is every step explained.

I'd recommend SopaUI too as @earandap mentioned.